# How to access FOUND while running a dynamic query in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, plpgsql

I have stored proc in Redshift in plpgsql.
When I run `call test3()` I get exception 
***Amazon Invalid operation: Row Count: 1;
1 statement failed.***

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  PROCEDURE test3()
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
     found_record RECORD;
     integer_var integer;
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO  found_record FROM tbl WHERE id='ABC';
IF FOUND THEN 
    GET DIAGNOSTICS integer_var = ROW_COUNT;
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Row Count: %', integer_var;
END IF;
END;
$$
```

But when I run `call test4()` I get

***0 rows affected
CALL executed successfully***

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  PROCEDURE test4()
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
     found_record RECORD;
     integer_var integer;
BEGIN

    EXECUTE  'SELECT *  FROM tbl WHERE id=\'ABC\'' into found_record ;
IF FOUND THEN 
    GET DIAGNOSTICS integer_var = ROW_COUNT;
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Row Count: %', integer_var;
END IF;
END;
$$
```

How do I access FOUND while executing dynamic query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic SQL has not a impact on `FOUND` variable. But you can use a `GET DIAGNOSTICS` statement. You do it in your example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  PROCEDURE test4()
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
   found_record RECORD;
   integer_var integer;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE  'SELECT *  FROM tbl WHERE id=\'ABC\'' into found_record ;
  GET DIAGNOSTICS integer_var = ROW_COUNT;
  RAISE EXCEPTION 'Row Count: %', integer_var;
END;
$$
```

You can use `GET DIAGNOSTICS` statement everywhere - not only when `FOUND` is true.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, however you can check that `found_record` is not null.